# Changing opacity with OBJMTLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently working on a project with three.js which include the usage of the OBJMTLloader.js, loading the obj and the mtl file

Here is my code:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( './three/obj/Colonne/Vertebres.obj','./three/obj/Colonne/Vertebres.mtl', function ( object ) {
    object.position.y = - 70;
    scene.add( object );
} );
```

I want to know if it is possible to change the opacity of the object/material once it's loaded. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Show your code and ask a specific question about it if you are having problems.

Comment: So here is my code :
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( './three/obj/Colonne/Vertebres.obj','./three/obj/Colonne/Vertebres.mtl', function ( object ) {
   object.position.y = - 70;
   scene.add( object );
  } );
I just want to know how can you change opacity, cause I tried to search, and I found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loader callback, you can use a pattern like this one:

```
object.traverse( function( node ) {
    if( node.material ) {
        node.material.opacity = 0.5;
        node.material.transparent = true;
    }
} );
```

three.js r.64