# Three js dat-gui: Change opacity and visibility of object coming from OBJMTL Loader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object loaded with by using OBJMTLLoader. I want to change the position, visibility and opacity of the loaded object from the dat-gui control panel. I tried to implement this [example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/GUI-Controller.html) and now can move the loaded object. However, to change the visibility and opacity. I think I need to use "materials" of the loaded object. I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825479/changing-opacity-with-objmtloader) but couldn't have success. Following is my code so far.

```
objects = [];
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener('load', function(event){
        object = event.content;
        object.traverse(function(child){
            if (child instanceof THREE.mesh) {
                //The child is needed for the raycaster intersection later
            };
        });
    });
    loader.load("models/Model1.obj", "models/Model1.mtl", function (object) {
                objects.push(object);
                scene.add(object);
    parameters = {
                    x:0, y:2, z:0,
                    opacity: 1, 
                    visible: true,
                    reset: function() { resetObject() }
                };
    var folder1 = gui.addFolder('Position');
                var objectX = folder1.add(parameters, 'x').min(-200).max(200).step(1).listen();
                //.............
                folder1.open();
                // moving model is OK. Deleted to save space...

                var objectOpacity = gui.add(parameters, 'opacity').min(0).max(1).step(0.01).name('Opacity').listen();
                objectOpacity.onChange(function(value){
                object.material.opacity = value;  });

                var objectVisible = gui.addColor( parameters, 'visible').name('Visible?').listen();
                objectVisible.onChange(function(value){
                object.material.visible = value;   });

                gui.add( parameters, 'reset' ).name("Reset Object Parameters");
                gui.open();
                // and the required functions as in the example.
```

With the above code, console gives following errors:

```
Uncaught Failed to interpret color arguments //dat.gui.min.js:87
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined
```

How can I adjust the visibility and opacity from the dat-gui panel? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`material.visible` defines whether this material is visible; not if the object is visible. If you want to make the object visible/invisible you need to use the `Object3D.visible` attribute so in the above code you need to do:

```
object.visible = value;
```

now for the material. the loader returns an `THREE.Object3D` not a `THREE.Mesh`. so you cannot access the material that way. what you need to do is:

```
object.traverse( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.opacity = value;
        child.material.transparent = true;
    }
});
```